# Not able to successfully parse python regex from reading the contents of a file

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I've got an issue where my regex isn't parsing the output of a file I created:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import wget, re
url=''
filename=wget.download(url)
with open ('Output.txt', "r") as f:
    readlines=f.read()
ret=re.sub("^.*\^", "", readlines)
print(ret)
```

According to this [site](https://www.debuggex.com/?flavor=python), the regex I'm using `"^.*\^"` is valid for my output. Sample output I'm feeding it is something like this:

```
1212-2010^readthispart
```

Where it has a carot for a delimiter. I tried double and single quotes to no avail and I'm not sure if it's an issue elsewhere in my code or what, but the printout does not match what I'm looking for. Ideas?

Comment: What are you looking for?

Comment: I'm looking to replace the `1212-2010^` part of a line in a text file.

Comment: What is the output you are getting?

Comment: `ret=re.sub(r"^.*\^", r"", readlines)` works fine, please clarify.

Comment: I needed to use a look-behind assertion because the actual regex wasn't replacing with emptiness.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm reading your question and edits right you're looking to return 'readthispart', correct?  If so you need to look into using look-behinds in combination with search.  See https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html.  `re.search("(?<=\^).*",myinput)`

Comment: Yep, that's it A. Scientist. This actually worked `(?!\^).*\^`

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable multiline mode:

```
re.sub('^.*\^', '', readlines, flags=re.MULTILINE)
```

Comment: Mmm, doesn't seem to be doing it's job of replacing all the text and carot with just the "readthispart" remaining.

Comment: @xorLogic Clarify what you want the output to be in your question.

Comment: Updated the answer